# Crazy audio MacBook Pro issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, speakers

I purchased a used MacBook Pro 2018 recently and it has developed an audio issue I cannot figure out. When trying to play sound through the speakers whatever the first sound I try to play after a restart works fine. Whether I play a YouTube video or change the volume level and hear the little indicator sound play it will work. However, if I move away from the sound (like switch YouTube videos, move to play a Spotify song, or again try to change the volume) the sound doesn't work. Nothing comes out of the speakers.

In Terminal, if I run the `sudo killall core audio` command then audio will begin working again, however, as soon as I load another YouTube video or switch audio streams it dies again! I get similar results if I close the lid of the laptop wait and beat and open it. The first sound will work and then nothing else!

This issue does not occur when using Bluetooth or wired headphones.

1. I have checked the audio output and it is correct
2. I have restarted many times
3. I have reset the PRAM
4. I have reformatted the computer completely (at the Big Sur level and upgraded to Monterey) and the issue STILL persists.

*edit to include additional trouble shooting
5. reset the SMC
6. change from 44 kHz to 48 kHz*

I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check Utilities/ Audio MIDI Setup for 'stray' 3rd party audio drivers. Try toggling your speaker output from 44 to 48 kHz (or vice versa)

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any stray drivers. I also tried switching the speaker output with no success.

Comment: While this might sound strange: Have you installed Parallels? If yes, open _System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Privacy>Allow the FULL ACCESS DISK for Paralles Desktop_.

After that, switch off your virtual windows (if running),  right click on Parallel icon on the right top of the monitor (two red lines). Click on _CONFIGURE_ and in the _CONFIGURATION WINDOWS_ of your virtual machine click _HARDWARE>CPU & MEMORY>ADVANCED_ and change the _HYPERVISOR_ from _Parallels_ to _Apple_.

Comment: if you haven’t installed and use Parallels - try repairing the disk permissions using Apple’s Disk Utility and delete _~Library/Preferences/com.apple.BezelServices.plist_ then restart your Mac and check.

Comment: Thanks @slartibartfast. I haven't installed parallels (or any software on this machine since the reset). 

I tried your second suggestion, but didn't have any success, unfortunately. Thanks.